# Google Sheets (Hide/Unhide row with script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, show-hide

I'm new to Google Sheets. I have a spreadsheet where I have one record per line. Everytime I finish entering a record I want it to unhide the row below it, could someone show me a simple script to do this? Also, I would want to clear all records and hide all but the first row in the record range, a bit help please.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [ask] and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const hr=1;
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet1' && e.range.rowStart>hr && e.range.columnStart==sh.getLastColumn()){
    sh.showRows(e.range.rowStart+1);
  }
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: There will be data in cells below and to the right of the record range, so that won't work. If it helps, it will never be more than 10 records. So maybe an onEdit trigger on the last cell for the first nine rows?

Comment: Improve your question and I may improve my answer but no guarantees.  As an alternative you can improve my answer on you on.

Comment: Sorry...I tried pasting a image but it wouldn't let me. I have a spreadsheet where I calculate the total sum up to 10 items. Range A:9 to B19 is where I'm entering my items, and below that is a tax, shipping, and total price field in range B20 to B22.  I enter my item description and then the item price, starting on row 9. After I'm done entering the price for the item on row 9 I want it to unhide row 10 and move cursor to A10. Then after I enter item description in A10 and item price in B10 I want it to unhide row 11, and so on.

Comment: I don't see any improvement to your question so I have nothing add.